# How is a nonnegative orthant a cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, polyhedra, convex-cone

My textbook says the following:

> The nonnegative orthant is the set of points with nonnegative components, i.e.,
>
> $$\mathbb{R}_+^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x_i \ge 0, i = 1, \dots, n\} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x \succeq 0 \}.$$
>
> (Here $\mathbb{R}_+$ denotes the set of nonnegative numbers: $\mathbb{R}_+ = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ge 0 \}.$) The nonnegative orthant is a polyhedron and a cone (and therefore called a *polyhedral cone*).

A *cone* is defined earlier in the textbook as follows:

> A set $C$ is called a cone, or nonnegative homogeneous, if for every $x \in C$ and $\theta \ge 0$ we have $\theta x \in C$.

A *polyhedron* is defined earlier in the textbook as follows:

> $$\mathcal{P} = \{ x \mid a_j^T x \le b_j, j = 1, \dots, m, c_j^T x = d_j, j = 1, \dots, p \}$$

I can see how a nonnegative orthant is a polyhedron, but I don't see why it is also a cone? For instance, according to the above definition of cone, there is no requirement that $x \ge 0$, unlike for a nonnegative orthant.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pick an element from the nonnegative orthant, $x$, then we have $x \ge 0$.

We take an arbitrary nonnegative number $\theta$ and construct the vector $y=\theta x$.

Each component of $y$ is $y_i=\theta x_i$ where $\theta \ge 0$ and $x_i \ge 0$, hence we have $y_i \ge 0$.

Hence $y$ still resides in the nonnegative octant.

Hence the nonnegative orthant is a cone.

The nonnegative orthant is a cone, it doesn't mean that all cone is a nonegative orthant. It is a special case of a cone, it can has special property such as having componentwise nonnegativity for each element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The definition of cone has $x \in C$, not necessarily $x \ge 0$. It seems you assumed that  $x \ge 0$?

Comment: We are verifying that the nonnegative orthant has the cone property. Hence we start by taking an element from the nonnegative orthant.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what I was misunderstanding: the nonnegative orthant is a *subset* of cone, so there exist cones that are not nonnegative orthants. Is that right?

Comment: yes, you can also check that the nonpositive orthant is also a cone.